# How to create thumbnail of a video

Tags: html, ionic3

I need a thumbnail in my `videogular2`.

I want to create a thumbnail/poster for my video. Currently it only shows a play/pause button with black screen and `vg-poster` is not working.

Here is my code:

```html
 <vg-player>
  <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play><vg-controls vg-autohide="false">                                        
  <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
  <vg-mute></vg-mute>
  </vg-controls><vg-poster vg-url="https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/styles/primary_image_in_article/public/image_nodes/sunflower-1627193_1920.jpg?itok=RUilemL3"></vg-poster>
<video height="200px" width="100%" [vgMedia]="media" #media src="{{server_path}}{{imgVid.data_path}}" id="singleVideo"                                        
autoplay></video>
</vg-player>
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTML 5 `video` tag has a [`poster`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp) attribute. From w3Schools:

> specifies an image to be shown while the video is downloading, or until the user hits the play button. If this is not included, the first frame of the video will be used instead.

In your example it would look like this:

```
<video 
  poster="https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/styles/primary_image_in_article/public/image_nodes/sunflower-1627193_1920.jpg" 
  height="200px" 
  width="100%" 
  [vgMedia]="media" 
  #media 
  src="{{server_path}}{{imgVid.data_path}}" 
  id="singleVideo"
  autoplay>
</video>
```